Uniqueness of a bounded addition-like operation on the closed interval from 0 to 1
For values $v_1, v_2 \in [0, 1]$, special relativity provides us with the addition rule
$$
v = v_1 \oplus v_2 := \frac{v_1 + v_2}{1+v_1 v_2}
$$
It is easy to check that the following conditions hold for $\oplus$:

commutative
associative
$ v_1 \oplus 0 = v_1$, neutral element
$ v_1 \oplus 1 = 1$, absorbing element
$ v_1 \oplus v_2 > v_1 \text{ for } v_1,v_2\in(0,1)$, the sum is larger than each term
the operation is continuous in each argument

NOTE: there is no inverse element because of 5.
Question: Is $\oplus$ as defined above unique on the unit interval in having all properties 1 to 6. If not, what would be a counterexample.
I tried $f_\tau(a,b) := (a\oplus b)^\tau$ for some fixed $\tau\neq 1$, but this is not associative. Similarly $f(a, b) := (a\oplus b) + (1- (a \oplus b))\cdot ab$ which tries to increase the result of $(a\oplus b)$ a bit into the gap up to $1$.
My hunch is that associativity somehow is the critical condition, but I can't get a contradiction. I started with
$$ g(a,b) := a\oplus b + \epsilon(a,b) $$
with $\epsilon$ providing a small deviation from $\oplus$, but could not prove a contradiction.
EDIT: heavily edited after understanding my actual problem better. Still no good tags.

If you exclude the points at $\pm 1$, then $(-1,1)$ with $\hat{+}$ is a group, isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with $+$.  Not unique; any monotonic bijection from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ would work the same way.

A group? How would you define and inverse element? $v \hat+ (-v) \ge v$, so surely $\neq0$.

@Harald the inequality in (5) is true only when you have positive velocities. From your definition, it is clear that $v\hat+(-v) = 0$.

The bijection in your case is $v\mapsto \tanh^{-1} v$.

I do have only positive velocities, they are all from $[0,1]$ as stated. The notation $(-v)$ symbolizes merely a supposed inverse element of $v$ which cannot exist.

The binary operation
$$v = v_1 \oplus v_2 := \frac{v_1 + v_2}{1+v_1 v_2}$$
is a so called t-conorm, often symbolized by "$\bot$". T-conorms are mostly defined as in the question. In particular it is the t-conorm to a Hamacher t-norm, a class of t-norms parametrized by one parameter, $p>0$. These t-conorms have the form
$$
\bot(x, y, p) = \frac{p x y - 2 x y + x + y}{p x y - x y + 1}
$$
and for $p=2$ we get
$$x \oplus y = \bot(x,y, 2)\,.$$ Insofar the velocity addition is not unique, given the conditions.

This is a formal group law.
Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 28.
